# Column dividing for javascript object

Tags: javascript, sql, angular, object, ag-grid

So here is a javascript object data I just got from SQL database:

```
0: {ww: "2021-27", area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS", waiting_time: 5.3670104041}
1: {ww: "2021-26", area: "F15 METROLOGY", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", waiting_time: 0}
2: {ww: "2021-26", area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_FOR_START_RUNNING", waiting_time: 0.1858817617}
3: {ww: "2021-25", area: "F15 CMP", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", waiting_time: 0}
4: {ww: "2021-25", area: "F15 GENERAL", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS", waiting_time: 0.0326702424}
5: {ww: "2021-27", area: "F15 DRY ETCH", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", waiting_time: 0}
6: {ww: "2021-27", area: "F15 DIFFUSION", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", waiting_time: 1.544808954}
7: {ww: "2021-24", area: "F15 METROLOGY", dissection_name: "WAIT_FOR_START_RUNNING", waiting_time: 0.0270019481}
8: {ww: "2021-24", area: "F15 PHOTO", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", waiting_time: 0.0001341795}
9: {ww: "2021-24", area: "F15 DRY ETCH", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", waiting_time: 0}
```

I want to apply some manipulation to it, so that the "waiting_time" column name will be changed with its 'ww' value for each data piece to convert the object structure like this:

```
0: {area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS", 2021-27: 5.3670104041}
    1: { area: "F15 METROLOGY", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", 2021-27: 0}
    2: { area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_FOR_START_RUNNING", 2021-26: 0.1858817617}
    3: { area: "F15 CMP", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", 2021-26: 0}
    4: { area: "F15 GENERAL", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS", 2021-25: 0.0326702424}
    5: { area: "F15 DRY ETCH", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", 2021-25: 0}
    6: {area: "F15 DIFFUSION", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", 2021-24: 1.544808954}
    7: { area: "F15 METROLOGY", dissection_name: "WAIT_FOR_START_RUNNING", 2021-24: 0.0270019481}
    8: { area: "F15 PHOTO", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", 2021-23: 0.0001341795}
    9: { area: "F15 DRY ETCH", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", 2021-23: 0}
```

The ultimate goal is actually loading the converted data into a angular ag-grid table like this:

table example:

```
area dissection_name 2021-24 2021-25 2021-26 2021-27 
xxx   xxx                0     1.55  2.33    5.3670   
xxx   xxx                xxx    xxx   xxx     xxx
```

Is there a way to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to project the data in the form you want:

```
const finalData = rawData.map((item) => {
  const { ww, waiting_time, ...dataItem } = item;
  return {
    ...dataItem,
    [ww]: waiting_time
  };
});
```